# General relativistic version of Rankine–Hugoniot jump conditions in fluid dynamics

Tags: general-relativity, fluid-dynamics, conservation-laws, boundary-conditions

Is there anything like [Rankine-Hugoniot jump conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rankine%E2%80%93Hugoniot_conditions) for general relativity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, to glue together in [GR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_relativity) two [Lorentzian manifolds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudo-Riemannian_manifold)  (possibly with matter) along a common boundary (which could contain a [brane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brane)), the Israel junction conditions should be satisfied, cf. e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/629419/2451) related Phys.SE post.

This is by the way similar to the [interface conditions between two media in E&M](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_conditions_for_electromagnetic_fields).