# Terms in the Israel Junction Conditions

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, curvature, stress-energy-momentum-tensor, boundary-conditions

I'm confused about the Israel Junction Conditions. I've seen them written several different ways so far, but here I'll use: $$K^-_{ij}-K^+_{ij}=8\pi(S_{ij}-\frac{1}{2}g_{ij}S).$$

My understanding is that $K^-_{ij}$ and $K^+_{ij}$ are the extrinsic curvatures of the shell measured from the inside and outside respectively, $S_{ij}$ is the energy-momentum tensor of the induced metric on the shell, $S$ is its trace, and $g_{ij}$ is the metric of the resulting manifold after the two are combined.

1. But I've seen it written in other ways too.  [This is another way I’ve seen it written.](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/629419/) Do those other ways mean the same thing as this?
2. Also, does this apply for any case of two Lorentzian manifolds being glued?

Here is the image I got the first equation from:

[image]

Comment: I wanted to answer but the option isn't there anymore as the question is closed. The conditions do apply for Lorentzian manifolds. In AdS/CFT, when taking the CPT-conjugation and conformally completing a coarse-grained wedge, one uses these Barrabes-Isreal conditions to identify the codimension-2 extremal surface to find the conformal completion of the coarse-graining. As of the first part, I am not sure what the other ways are, but technically the idea is to identify conditions to glue objects across some surface without discontinuities. I hope that answers your question.

Comment: But did I get the terms right? Also, aren’t there cases where a continuous metric isn’t realizable?

Answer (score 1):

1. This is just a trace-reversed version of the [EFE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_field_equations) on the hypersurface, i.e. the 2nd Israel junction condition. This is equivalent to the forward version. (Recall there is also a trace-reversed version of the EFE in the bulk.)
2. The gluing of 2 Lorentzian manifolds along a common hypersurface satisfying the EFE is given by Israel's 2 junction conditions, cf. e.g. Ref. 1.

References:

1. Eric Poisson, *A Relativist's Toolkit,* 2004; space-like/time-like hypersurface: section 3.7 + null-like hypersurface: section 3.11.

Comment: The Israel conditions are only valid for a timelike or spacelike hypersurface though. The mentioned book also contains a separate discussion for the null case. It is also possible to treat all hypersurfaces simultaneously (including those whose signature is non-constant), e.g. https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/0264-9381/10/9/026 . But then the equations are more complicated.

Comment: $\uparrow$ Good point.

Comment: Thank you, these responses are really helpful.